# Vuetify: Dynamic v-tabs model change does not always work

Tags: vuetify.js

The expected behavior is that Tab1 should be selected when Tab3 is closed using the X-mark. Instead, no tab gets selected. This is strange, because when I re-assign the tab.value using the button in the exact same way, then it works.

Code ([Playground link](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/?preview=false#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)):

```
<template>
  <v-app>
    <v-card>
      <v-tabs v-model="tab" bg-color="primary">
        <v-tab v-for="(t, index) in visibleTabs" :key="t">
          {{ t.name }}
          <v-icon x-small class="ml-2" @click="hideTab(t)">mdi-close</v-icon>
        </v-tab>
      </v-tabs>

      <v-card-text>
        <v-window v-model="tab">
          <v-window-item v-for="(t, index) in visibleTabs" :key="t">
            {{ t.name }}
          </v-window-item>
        </v-window>
      </v-card-text>
    </v-card>

    <v-btn @click="selectedTabFirstTab">Select first tab</v-btn>
  </v-app>
</template>

<script setup>
  import { ref, computed } from 'vue'

  const tab = ref(0)
  const allTabs = ref([
    { name: 'Tab1', visible: true },
    { name: 'Tab2', visible: true },
    { name: 'Tab3', visible: true },
  ])
  const visibleTabs = computed(() => allTabs.value.filter(tab => tab.visible))

  function hideTab(t) {
    t.visible = false
    // Closing last tab should re-select the first tab
    if (t.name == 'Tab3') {
      tab.value = 0 // This does not work
    }
  }

  function selectedTabFirstTab() {
    tab.value = 0 // This works!
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The part of code in your hideTab function to switch tab actually works, but since there is a click in the `Tab3` as well, the model value `tab` is again switched back to `2`.

You can try the hide handler with event.stopPropagation like:

```js
<template>
  ...
  <v-icon x-small class="ml-2" @click.prevent="hideTab($event, t)"
  ...
</template>
<script>
function hideTab(event, t) {
  event.stopPropagation()
  t.visible = false  
  // logic to switch tabs
}
</script>
```

This avoids the further click event transfer in the tab element and should switch the tab for you.